# Tweak Wazuh to show alerts of out-of-the-ordinary activity

Tags: wazuh

I installed Wazuh, and got a running agent on some test machine to connect to it, and I can see the logs in Wazuh and all the alerts that are firing. Now my goal is to tweak the alerts that are displayed, because most of them are just regular activity which is not suspicious, and I only want to see activity which deviates from what we are familiar with. Only in the case that there is an incident investigation - I would still need to be able to see the entire sesssion, from logon (which is not bad or susicious in itself) to the point where bad things started to happen, so I do need all the logs to be stored (they just shouldn't interfere me from seeing the stuff that's worth investigating).

How do I achieve this? Do I need to change the rules that fire all these alerts? Do I do that by setting the rules' loglevel to 0, or can I delete the rules entirely and still be able to find the log when I do an inestigation? How can I practically tweak so many rules, as Wazuh comes with thousands of predefined rules?

Or maybe I should go about it in a different approach? What would the right approach be, please?

I tried learning about decoders and rules to understand if that can help me, but it seems like I'd only need that when trying to monitor 3rd part devices or services which Wazuh doesn't know out-of-the-box. I couldn't find how to configure Wazuh to differentiate between regular activities and bad events.

Thanks a lot in advance for any explanation that can help me !

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal of only seeing alerts for suspicious activity while still being able to access all the logs for incident investigation, there are a few approaches you can take:

- First of all, it's important to analyze whether it's necessary to completely silence an alert or if it can be filtered in the dashboard to not appear in the general view, but still be available for consultation if necessary. In some cases, an alert that may not seem relevant at first glance may actually be relevant in the context of a larger investigation, so it's important to consider filtering rather than silencing alerts.
- Modify the existing rules: Wazuh comes with thousands of predefined rules, and you can modify the rules that fire these alerts to make them more specific to your needs. You can change the rule's log level to 0, which will prevent the alerts from being displayed in the Wazuh dashboard, but the logs will not be stored. Alternatively, you can modify the rule's condition to make it more specific, so it only fires for suspicious activity.
- Create new rules: If the predefined rules don't suit your needs, you can create new rules that are specific to your environment. You can create rules that look for specific patterns of activity that are indicative of malicious behavior.
  You can find more information about rules syntax an creating rules from scratch in the following documentation links:

  - https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/ruleset/ruleset-xml-syntax/rules.html
  - https://wazuh.com/blog/creating-decoders-and-rules-from-scratch/
- When it comes to tweaking rules, you don't need to modify all of the rules. Instead, focus on the rules that are generating the most noise in your environment. You can start by looking at the alerts that are firing most frequently and see if there is a way to make the rule more specific or change the log level. Once you have addressed the most problematic rules, you can move on to others as needed.
- Another useful option is to configure alert levels to receive email notifications only for the most important and critical alerts. You can configure Wazuh to send email alerts based on alert severity levels, so you can receive notifications when there is a high or critical alert that requires immediate attention. This can help you to focus on the most important alerts and reduce alert fatigue from receiving too many notifications.
- Also, you can group alerts using the "timeframe" and "frequency" option to group alerts that occur within a certain period of time and with a certain frequency.
  By grouping alerts, you can avoid receiving multiple alerts for the same issue and instead receive a single alert with a summary of the events. This can make it easier to manage alerts and reduce the amount of noise in the dashboard.

You can find more information and use cases to explore different Wazuh capabilities in the following documentation link: https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/proof-of-concept-guide/index.html

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any specific questions or if there is anything else I can do to help

Regards,

Guido